# How do i print all possible value of class property in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging

I just start to learn unity and currently following the [tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/touch-input-for-mobile-scripting-2019). I'm curious when I following the last section of the tutorial, I got `NaN` value in one of the code, so I tried to logging it to know where's the `NaN` came from.

I've tried to use this code to logging it

```
Debug.Log("The Touch => ");
Debug.Log(theTouch);
```

but the value in `adb logcat` only show me (I'm using [logkitty](https://github.com/zamotany/logkitty))

[image: Logging]

so, how do i properly get all value inside `Touch`/`Input` class? something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(theObject))` in `Javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from my experience as a Unity developer, there is no need to do that, but probably if you look up, you will find a class that joins all the fields into a String.

Usually you just look for the fields you need to debug and you join them yourself, it is way more efficient to do that (programming wise).

For example if you wanted to get some information about a Rigidbody (physics component) you would do:

```
Debug.Log(rigidbody.velocity + " the magnitude of this velocity is: " + rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);
```

Comment: how to know if `rigidbody` has a `velocity` as a variable? I mean, i not familiar with Unity (yet), so is there any function to let me know that this `class` contain `class.subVar`?

Comment: you have to use an IDE like visual studio code, and you add the Unity extension, so it is the IDE itself showing you what there is insite the rigidbody class! (write "rigidbody." and press Ctrl+Space)